# Accessing full Android storage

Tags: root-access, files, folders

What was the last version of Android which allowed apps and user to have full read and write access along with all copy move or delete operations of everything inside the internal storage?

Currently, I am using a Samsung Galaxy S8.

Answer (score 2):

The last Android version that used what is now called the `legacy external storage system` was Android 10. In that system all apps could request full read or full read&write access to the shared internal storage.

Starting with Android 11 apps have to use `scoped storage` by default. Only older apps targeting Android 10 are able to request access to internal storage using the legacy storage system. [Storage updates in Android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage#scoped-storage). And I think I have read that it also makes a difference if your phone has been upgraded from Android 10 to 11 or if it was originally released with Android 11.

On Android 12 and newer it doesn't matter which Android version the app is targeting, they all have to use the scoped storage system without any exceptions.

Comment: I bought a pixel 7 during black friday did i make a mistake by buying a lemon phone ? If scoped storsge is so limited compared to android 9 on my galaxy s8 is it even worth keeping it ? I really really am disliking and forming hatred towards my pixel 7. Is rooting the pixel 7 going to make any difference ?

Comment: @anmac1789 The scoped storage is a bit challenging for developers, but it can be handled. In the end it is not a bug but a feature: Apps only get access to folders they really need, so not every app you install for testing can upload all your private photos to some shady server unless you really want it. Scoped storage will stay, so get used to it or don't use Android anymore.

Comment: I dont like the idea of scoped storage at all. Is there any lesser storage difference between android 9 and android 10 ? I am using a webdav server app on my galaxy s8 which enabled me to see all the files and folders on the whole android system that I can use to backup my phone with. I want to retain this level of full access

I am worried if this will affect whatsapp, telegram, snap, IG and others and file manager interchangeability because I use these social media and file manager apps very often

Comment: @anmac1789 There are certain apps excluded from the scoped storage rule. File managers can still get full access using the new MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission. As far as I know only apps where the main functionality requires full storage access are granted this permission (respectively make it through the Google app review process).

Comment: But how do I know which apps have this permission ? I mainly use solid file explorer and File Manager+ those are very dependable for me. How do I know which apps are being limited by scoped storage ?

Comment: @anmac1789 Just look at the Play Store comments of each app. If it would no longer work on Android 11, 12 and 13 you would find plenty of negative comments there.

Comment: What about rooting would that make a better difference?

Comment: @anmac1789 Apps that use root permissions bypass all restrictions of the Android Java API. But to me it seems like you are thinking too much about restrictions that don't affect you. Just make sure the apps you use has been updated in the last two years and check their Play Store reviews. All apps that has been updated should be aware of scoped storage. Just try it out yourself before making unnecessary changes to your system.

Comment: The main one I find useful is File Manager+ which ironically since version 3.1.0 supports android 13 and is in 3.1.3 of its latest version (Checked since Jan 22 2023)